# Any difference between EPSG:3003 and EPSG:102091?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am working on QGIS 2.2.0.

The PRS I am working on is Monte Mario / Italy zone 1 (EPSG:3003), with the following parameters:

```
PROJCS["Monte Mario / Italy zone 1",
GEOGCS["Monte Mario",
    DATUM["Monte_Mario",
        SPHEROID["International 1924",6378388,297,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7022"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6265"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4265"]],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",1500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","3003"],
AXIS["X",EAST],
AXIS["Y",NORTH]]
```

A dataset I need to use on the above PRS is in Monte_Mario_Italy_1 (EPSG:102091), with the following parameters:

```
PROJCS["Monte_Mario_Italy_1",
GEOGCS["GCS_Monte_Mario",
    DATUM["Monte_Mario",
        SPHEROID["International_1924",6378388,297]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["False_Easting",1500000],
PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],
PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9],
PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0],
UNIT["Meter",1],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","102091"]]
```

Is there any difference between the two PRS? (I see a difference in decimals in parameter UNIT["Degree", ...]).

In other words, do I need a re-projection or datum transformation to analyse the data together (e.g. buffering, calculating distances etc) ?

Thanks in advance.
Alessandro

Comment: Looks same, You can test it in QGIS if it has both srid in system, set onfly projection off , load data and set to correct proj, then see if it looks correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference in the proj definition:

EPSG:3003

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-104.1,-49.1,-9.9,0.971,-2.917,0.714,-11.68 +units=m +no_defs
```

EPSG:102091

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs
```

The first one has a datum shift (+towgs84), the second not.

The second is not a defintion by EPSG, but invented by ESRI. They do not write datum shifts into their projection definitions, but keep them separate.

In any case, I suggest to use the first one inside QGIS. But do not reproject the second to the first, instead use `Set CRS for Layer`, then save to disk under another name.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have to correct this (sorry I am a newbie of course): the EPSG:102091 is AUTOMATICALLY SELECTED by QGIS. My data is a raster dataset (DTM, Altitude) with the following associated prj.adf:  Projection: TRANSVERSE -- Datum: MOD -- Spheroid: INT1909 -- Units: METERS -- Zunits: NO -- Xshift: 0.0 -- Yshift: 0.0 -- Parameters: 0.9996 -- /* scale factor at central meridian:
   9  0  0.0 /* longitude of central meridian --
   0  0  0.0 /* latitude of origin --
1500000.0 /* false easting (meters) --
0.0 /* false northing (meters). Does this correctly correspond to EPSG:102091?

Comment: This corresponds to both, as no datum shift is specified. I would nethertheless use EPSG:3003.

Comment: 102091 is Esri's. We added that CRS before it was added to the EPSG registry. Disclosure: Esri employee and member of EPSG registry committee.

Comment: @mkennedy: I still favour to call it ESRI:102091, not EPSG:102091. Would ESRI have anything against it?

Comment: @AndreJoost No, of course not. In fact, 102091 should never be identified as EPSG's, but a lot of software (including some of ours) doesn't differentiate.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the transformation between EPSG:3003 and EPSG:102091 in an unambiguous way with the GDAL tool "gdaltransform" http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html

```
GDAL_dev>gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:3003 -t_srs epsg:102091
100000 100000
100000.113807246 99999.9986070729 0
```

Test with your own coordinates. There seems to be a little difference and you are the only one who knows if 10 cm accuracy is good enough.

Comment: I have a feeling that if you set the target to epsg:3003, it would also show close to the same output--I'm surprised that there's that much difference (just from the different DD/rad value? Must test it). Disclosure: Esri employee

Comment: Oh, the transformation may be occurring as well using the towgs84 values.